# Query in data population using select in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I am populating data using

```
<select name="test">
<option value='<%=session.getAttribute("tList")%>'><%=session.getAttribute("tList") %></option>

</select>
```

but the values are getting display in a single row in the combo box not row wise,where i am going wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest adding a jstl loop:

```
<select name="test">
    <c:forEach items="${sessionScope.tList}" var="item">
        <option value="${item}">${item}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```